How about customizing the graph dataset to iteratively fetch batch
In my customized dataset there are only feature matrices and adjacency matrices.The feature matrix is a 4000×3000 one-dimensional tensor,and edge_index is torch.Size([2, 18708])
My code is :
from torch_geometric.data import Data
data = Data(x=features,edge_index=edge_index.t().contiguous())
from torch_geometric.data import DataLoader
loader = DataLoader(data,batch_size=128,shuffle=True)
for batch in loader:
    batch


bug is :
File ~/miniconda3/envs/spacel/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py:521, in _BaseDataLoaderIter.__next__(self)
    519 if self._sampler_iter is None:
    520     self._reset()
--> 521 data = self._next_data()
    522 self._num_yielded += 1
    523 if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \
    524         self._IterableDataset_len_called is not None and \
    525         self._num_yielded > self._IterableDataset_len_called:

File ~/miniconda3/envs/spacel/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py:561, in _SingleProcessDataLoaderIter._next_data(self)
    559 def _next_data(self):
    560     index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
--> 561     data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
    562     if self._pin_memory:
    563         data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/spacel/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py:49, in _MapDatasetFetcher.fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
     47 def fetch(self, possibly_batched_index):
     48     if self.auto_collation:
...
File ~/miniconda3/envs/spacel/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch_geometric/data/storage.py:111, in BaseStorage.__getitem__(self, key)
    110 def __getitem__(self, key: str) -> Any:
--> 111     return self._mapping[key]

KeyError: 0

Why is there this bug?And how to fix it.

As can be read in the documentation here, a Pytorch Geometric Dataloader does not accept a Data object as 'dataset'. Convert your Data object to a list of Data object (which represents a list of graphs) or convert it to a Dataset object. A dataset object requires your to implement some more functions however, so if you already know what your data will be, I recommend using a list of Data objects.
